My Flutter StreamBuilder isn't updating when a new user is created. The stream is based on Firebase Authentication
This is main file where stream builder is used:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Twitter Clone',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const loading();
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Homepage();
          }
          return const startingscreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


When a user is not authenticated, the app navigates to the starting screen, then proceeds to the email screen, followed by the email verification screen, password screen, username screen, and so forth (by Navigator.Push). Once the user completes the authentication process and a new account is created, the home screen does not appear.
It's strange to see that the login process works properly, navigating from the starting screen to the email screen, then to the password screen, and finally the homepage appears. However, in the case of a new user, the homepage does not appear.

Your code is correct, What is the error and where you facing issue?

what is your forth screen i think error occurs this screen. you tell by Navigator.Push

I don't see code where you actually look at the value of your stream.  If the stream is null, you have logged out.  If the stream has a User, you're logged in.  That should be the choice of showing the login page or the main page.
